# Determine class instance of a member in C++

Tags: c++

I've never seen this in any language, but I was wondering if this is possible using some trick that I don't know.

Let's say that I have a function like

```
struct A {
  // some members and methods ...
  some_t t;
  // more members ...
};   


void test(some_t& x) { // a reference to avoid copying a new some_t
    // obtain the A instance if x is the t member of an A 
    // or throw an error if x is not the t member of an A
    ...
    // do something
}
```

Would it be possible to obtain the instance of `A` whose member `t` is `x` ?

Comment: What are you trying to do? You're probably asking the wrong question.

Comment: obtain it from where? the void? don't understand what you're trying to do, but the thing your asking not only it's not possible, but I don't think it makes too much sense

Comment: Not possible unless all A's are registered in a dictionary. How do we otherwise know that all some_t's are members of an A? Some might be part of a B!

Comment: Nope, not even the most dynamic of dynamic languages support this.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I would have written a more specific example that would explain why I wanted to do such a weird thing, but I did not want to diverge the attention to *how* to re-structure things to achieve something similar, which is what I will do eventually.

Comment: You can (kinda) I posted an answer, but deleted it because it would not meet all your requirements. Given a pointer to a member variable you can figure out what the instance pointer is, but if what you are given was not, in fact, a pointer to a member variable you would not be able to detect it and come up with a nonsense pointer. As others have said if this is not being asked out of academic curiosity you are doing something very, very wrong.

Comment: @idz please repost - I'd love to see it.

Comment: @Neil my compiler disagrees with you. Provided you know which member variable it is and what class/struct it is a member variable of, yes, you can. You can use `offsetof` and pointer arithmetic.

Comment: idz's solution was essentially a c++ implementation of the `container_of` macro other's suggested, and it had the same shortcomings.

Comment: @Dennis and @Ben apologies I did not see Ben's post (and in any case I was not aware of `container_of`). Ya learn something new every day ;-) Even if it something you shouldn't. I think one of @Neil's comments summed it up "Or possibly, fortunately [you can't]"

Comment: @idz: The pointer arithmetic works only when the object *is* a member; you cannot *determine* this if you don't know in advance.  Your compiler will happily let you enter UB-land if you try by forcing the issue with a cast, however.

Comment: @Fred Nurk all of which I mentioned in my answer!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you know that you have a reference to the `t` member of some `A` instance, you can get the instance using [`container_of`](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v2.6.38/include/linux/kernel.h#L551), e.g. `A* pa = container_of(&x, A, t);`.

Verifying that the resulting pointer actually is an `A` is technically possible if and only if `A` has virtual members, unfortunately there's no portable method to check.

You can achieve something similar, however, using multiple inheritance and `dynamic_cast`, which allows cross-casting between subobjects.

Comment: Oh! I didn't expect that one to exist, let me check it out

Comment: `container_of` has been added to the C++ standard? Cool! When did that happen?

Comment: @Neil: It is easily implemented using `offsetof`, which is part of the C++ standard, so your sarcastic ravings are rather pointless.  Although it is worth pointing out that the results of `offsetof` [and, thus, `container_of`] are only well defined in C++ if `A` is POD.

Comment: @Dennis I tend to take the general view here. If the OP had said "can I for a POD determine if a member is an instance", then I might have said yes. But he didn't. structs are used on this tag as  as shorthand for classes with all members public, but (possibly) with virtual functions, and that is what I thought he was asking about. And nothing alters the fact that container_of is not (and never will be) part of C++.

Comment: @Neil: That's why I provided a link to the definition.

Answer (score 5):

No unfortunately it's not possible.

Comment: There are very few things the C++ compiler will not allow you to do, if you ask using enough casts.

Comment: @Ben And by applying those casts you are almost certainly invoking undefined or unspecified behavior.

Answer (score 1):

You can add pointer to `A` inside `some_t` (of course if `some_t` is `struct` or `class`)

like this:

```
struct some_t
{
  A *a;
  ...
};

void test(some_t& x) 
{
  if( x.a )
  {
    // do some
  }
  else
    throw ...
}
```

Comment: Is there some deeply clueless person who lurks on the c++ tags upvoting answers like this? It certainly seems so. If this describes you - please stop now.

Comment: You'd want to flesh out the implementation somewhat, but this could actually work.  Make `a` const, and only set it to a non-null value in a private constructor only accessible from `A`.  It would be flimsy, and probably the wrong way to solve whatever problem the OP has, but it would do the trick.

Comment: I do understand what YuppieNetworking wants. In this specific case it will work. Of course he can't check whether `x` is member of another class.

Answer (score 1):

This answer does not meet all the requirements of the original question, I had deleted it, but the OP requested I post it. It shows how *under very specific conditions* you can calculate the instance pointer from a pointer to a member variable.

You *shouldn't*, but you can:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstddef>

using namespace std;

struct A
{
    int x;
    int y;
};

struct A* find_A_ptr_from_y(int* y)
{
    int o = offsetof(struct A, y);
    return (struct A*)((char *)y - o);
}

int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
    struct A a1;
    struct A* a2 = new struct A;

    cout << "Address of a1 is " << &a1 << endl;
    cout << "Address of a2 is " << a2 << endl;

    struct A *pa1 = find_A_ptr_from_y(&a1.y);
    struct A *pa2 = find_A_ptr_from_y(&(a2->y));

    cout << "Address of a1 (recovered) is " << pa1 << endl;
    cout << "Address of a2 (recovered) is " << pa2 << endl;
}
```

Output

```
Address of a1 is 0x7fff5fbff9d0
Address of a2 is 0x100100080
Address of a1 (recovered) is 0x7fff5fbff9d0
Address of a2 (recovered) is 0x100100080
```

Caveats: if what you pass to `find_A_ptr_from_y` is not a pointer to (struct A).y you well get total rubbish.

You should (almost) never do this. See comment by DasBoot below.

Comment: Thanks for re-posting, these are the same results I am getting with `container_of`: indeed, if the pointer does not point to the member, the result will be rubbish.

Comment: I didn't even know about `container_of`.

Comment: As with many statements that say that you should *never* do something, I think there are actually a lot of exceptions. If you encapsulate it into a well known macro ( as the Linux Kernel does with container_of() ), then it's use is pretty safe, and can save a lot of passing around of useless extra pointers.

Comment: @DasBoot that is very true! I've used it myself in device drivers (that's how I knew about it). Perhaps I should have said *unless you really know what you are doing*.

Answer (score 1):

*If* you can modify struct A and its constructor and *if* you can ensure the structure packing, you can add a value directly after t which holds some magic key.

```
struct A {
  ...
  some_t t
  struct magic_t
  { 
    uint32 code
    some_t* pt;
  } magic;
}
#define MAGICCODE 0xC0DEC0DE //or something else unique
```

In A's constructor, do:
      `this->magic.code = MAGICCODE; this->magic.pt = &(this->t);`
Then you can write

```
bool test(some_t *t)  //note `*` not `&`
{
    struct magic_t* pm = (struct magic_t*)(t+1);
    return (pm->pt == t && pm->code == MAGICCODE);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not quite clear to me what you are trying to do, but if you are want to find the pointer to an instance of struct A when you know the pointer to a member of A, you can do that.

See for example the c[ontainer_of](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+%2a/tools/perf/util/include/linux/kernel.h#L18) macro in the linux kernel.

Answer (score 0):

The parameter `x` of function `test()` need not be a member of any class as far as `test()` is converned.

If semantically in a particular application `x` must always be a member of a class then that information could be provided, either by passing an additional paraemter or having `some_t` itself contain such information.  However to do that would be enturely unnecessary since if `test()` truely needed access to the object containing `x`, then why not simply pass the parent object itself?  Or just make `test()` a member function of the same class and pass no paraemeters whatsoever?  If the reason is because `x` may belong to differnt classes, then polymorphism can be employed to resolve that issue.

Basically I suggest that there is no situation where you would *need* such a capability that cannot be solved in a simpler, safer and more object oriented manner.